# Errors thrown in graphql custom directive not caught in useGlobalFilters Exception

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo, apollo-server

I have a graphQL Nest application in which i have a custom Auth directive which checks if a field can be retrieved by a user role. If it doesnot it throws a forbidden Error.

I also have used the `useGlobalFilters` method of nest application to register a global exception handler for logging, but the function is not invoked when the error is thrown by this directive

Directive

```
export class AuthorizeDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field: GraphQLField<any, any>) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

    field.resolve = async function(...args) {
      const [, queryArgs, ctx ] = args;
      let isAuthorized = false;
      if (accessCheckClass) {
        const instance: IAccessCheck = new AccessCheckClass();
        const result = instance.checkAccess(queryArgs, ctx);
        isAuthorized = result;
        if (result instanceof Promise) {
           isAuthorized = await result;
        }
      }

      if (isAuthorized) {
        return resolve.apply(this, args);
      }
      
    

      throw new ForbiddenError('Permission denied');
        
    };
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter()); --- AllExceptionsFilter.catch not getting called
```

Error thrown to the user

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
        "message": "permission denied",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 5
            }
        ],
        "path": [
            ""
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "FORBIDDEN",
            "exception": {
                "stacktrace": [
                ]     
            }
        }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "data": null
  }
}
```

Comment: What do the errors show up like?

Comment: Have added the error thrown to the user @JayMcDoniel